# SQL Where Clause with Contains

Tags: sql-server

I am using NopCommerce 3.5 and am trying to modify the SQL Stored Procedure to be able to search SKU

My Question is how do I get the following SQL to also check if the Column Value is also contained in the Keywords?

```
--SKU
    IF @SearchSku = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        UNION
        SELECT p.Id
        FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE '
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + '(CONTAINS(p.[Sku], @Keywords) OR CONTAINS(@Keywords, p.[Sku])) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + '(PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Sku]) > 0 OR PATINDEX(p.[Sku], @Keywords) > 0) '
    END
```

Comment: try wrapping p.sku with wildcards. e.g. `patindex('%' + p.[sku] + '%', @keywords`

Comment: That worked!! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping p.sku with wildcards. e.g. `patindex('%' + p.[sku] + '%', @keywords)`

Answer (score 0):

Xedni's comment above helped solved my issue. Changed the SQL Statement to the following.

```
--SKU
    IF @SearchSku = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        UNION
        SELECT p.Id
        FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE '
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + '(CONTAINS(p.[Sku], @Keywords) OR CONTAINS(@Keywords, ''%'' + p.[Sku] + ''%'')) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + '(PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Sku]) > 0 OR PATINDEX(''%'' + p.[Sku] + ''%'', @Keywords) > 0) '
    END
```